# JavaScript Array not indexing properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```
var graphdata = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], [0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25]];

function randomData (){
    var labels = graphdata[0]
    var labels2 = graphdata[1];
    console.log();
    return labels.map(function(labels, labels2){
        console.log(labels2);
        return { label: labels , value: labels2 }
    });
}
```

`labels` iterates correctly for A, B, C, D. but `labels2` gets squashed to 0, 1, 2, 3, and I am not sure why. Right before the `return labels.map()` call, if I `console.log()`, I can get the properly fractions to output but after that those values disappear and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument given to the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback is the index of the element in the iteration.

It looks like what you want would be

```
return labels.map(function(label, i){
    return { label: label , value: labels2[i] }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a callback with the parameters for the *current Element*, *current index* (optional) and the *original array* (optional).

`randomArray.map(function(currentElement, currentIndex, randomArrayAgain) { /*...*/})`

You could do:

```
labels.map(function(label, index) {
    return { label: label, value: labels2[index] }
});
```

### Explanaion

`map()` will iterate over `labels` and in each iteration you have access to the current label and index. This solution works only when your arrays are sorted in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation of `map` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The callback to the map function takes two parameters, first being each item in the list that is to be iterated over, and second the index or key of that item in the list. The `labels2` variable in your map callback doesn't refer to the one you created, it refers to the index of the item being mapped upon. Your implementation can be written as follows and it would be the same.

```
labels.map(function(eachLabel, key) {
    console.log(key); // 0, 1, 2, 3... (label.length - 1)
    return { label: eachLabel , value: key }
  });
```

Comment: (you mean the documentation, not the implementation)

Answer (score 0):

`map()` doesn't work this way.

The second parameter to `map()` is the index of the element it is currently looking at. So each time through it sets the first parameter `labels` to the element from `labels` that it's currently mapping the sets `labels2` to the index of `labels`.

Here's more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map